# prediction plots for statsmodels OLS fit, taking out categorical effects

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have some data for about 500 galaxies in a `pandas` DataFrame (a few hundred measurements per galaxy), and I'm trying to perform OLS regression on a few variables, one of which is categorical (each galaxy is its own category). Basically, once I have finished fitting the model, I want to plot the data, the fit, and some error bounds, *taking out the presumed effects of the categories themselves*.

In effect, I want to produce a plot much like the one in "OLS non-linear curve but linear in parameters" section of [this tutorial](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html) (replicated here).[image: from [statsmodels tutorials](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html)]

Instead, I have this (I've just picked two galaxies here, for ease of reading, but it gets really ugly with all 500):

[image: What I get with categorical variables]

Since there seem to be two "clusters" here, I have concluded that each must correspond to a galaxy. What I *really* want, though, is to collapse them down into a single line that takes out the inter-category effects, and imagines that they were all one galaxy.

For reference, the code that I'm using to fit and plot is:

```
m = sm.ols(
    formula='{} ~ Rdeproj + NSAMstar + \
             NSASersicN + C(plateifu)'.format(qty),
    data=dfr)
f = m.fit()
#print dir(f)

ypred = f.predict()
prstd, iv_l, iv_u = wls_prediction_std(f)

plt.close('all')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(dfr['Rdeproj'], dfr[qty], '.', label='data')
ax.plot(dfr['Rdeproj'], f.fittedvalues, 'r--.', label='pred')
ax.plot(dfr['Rdeproj'], iv_u, 'r--', label='bound')
ax.plot(dfr['Rdeproj'], iv_l, 'r--')
legend=ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$R_{deproj}$ [Mpc]')
ax.set_ylabel(qty)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('fits/' + qty + '_fit.png')
```

I found one similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948997/evaluate-slope-and-error-for-specific-category-for-statsmodels-ols-fit), but it seems to only address predicting observations for specific categories, rather than taking out those effects entirely.

Any further advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Even after taking out the categorical explanatory variable, you still have other variables that shift the predictions. If you want a plot with respect to one of the variables, then I guess it would be something like the partial  regression plot or the CCPR plot http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/regression_plots.html#Partial-Regression-Plots Neither of those has confidence intervals and I'm not sure how we would define them.

Comment: Very true, I guess I didn't think about that. The partial regression plots may prove useful. Thanks.